# Cannot reach Litestar on Railway API

Tags: python, litestar

- Forked [this repo](https://github.com/JacobCoffee/litestar-template/tree/main)
- Make local litestar app working
- Added .env
- Successfully built the app on Railway ('Application startup complete. Uvicorn running on [http://0.0.0.0:8000'](http://0.0.0.0:8000%27))

Now I cannot reach the API through any of the links:

> 'request timed out'

App:

[image: litestar template code]

What can I do to use the API remotely?

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: If you're having trouble using third-party code, maybe you should ask the developer of that code.

Comment: This appears to be the code that you use to create the app. What steps do you take to run the app? What steps do you take to try to use the API? (How did you determine that those should be the right steps?) When you say "Now I cannot reach the API through any of the links" - **what links are you referring to**, and how did you try to use them?

Answer (score 0):

10 hours later API starts working without any additional actions. It seems to me that Railway needs a couple of hours for litestar app to start working.